# Searching for a value and getting another value from a excel file using openpyxl with Python

Tags: python, search, openpyxl

I have a excel spreadsheet with different values. It looks like this:

```
Username | Lastseen | ID       | IDandsomething | 
Bob      |          | 555533aa | http555533aa   |
Mary     | 1 y ago  | 3993fj3a | http3993fj3a   |
Joe      | 1 d ago  | u7783ifd | httpu7783ifd   |
```

Now I have a python script where I get the ID and then I want to look for the right Username

I am german so I have this:

```
benutzerid = ID
benutzer = Username
```

My code:

```
....

print(benutzerid)
if not benutzerid.find ("/") >= 0: #if there is a slash something is wrong
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook("list.xlsx", read_only=True, data_only=True)
    ws_obj = wb_obj.active
 
    for row in ws_obj.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=20, max_col=500):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == benutzerid: #id is unique, there is only 1 id which matches, but the id is part of some other values in the same row like above
                print ("benutzerid: " + benutzerid)
                print(ws_obj.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column))
                benutzer=ws_obj.cell(cell.row, cell.column-9).value #this is the right column and it is also the first column in the row
                print ("benutzer: " + benutzer)
                break #break the loop because I have found the right value

    try:
        benutzer
    except NameError:
        benutzer = "UNKNOWNUSER" #use defaultvalue if no ID is found
    print (benutzer)
```

Clearly it does not work this way. I often get "UNKNOWNUSER" when I have the user in the list and I even don't get the right username back despite finding the right cell.

Don't know what to do ...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The ID is in a single column, lets assume Column C, why search every column from 1 to 500? Search column C only, will save a lot of time searching unnecessary cells. Also your break will only break out of the `for cell in row` loop but still continue the `for row in ...` loop. But otherwise if `cell.column-9` points to the username Column (obviously different to the example data provided) you should get what you want.

Comment: It sounds like you want to convert the rows to records, indexed by the user id.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example data and assuming your columns are A B C & D
the following example will return the user name for the ID and stop.
You can apply the same to your actual Sheet.

```
import openpyxl

def search(id):
    ### if min row/col is 1 there is no need to specify 
    ### Search Column C (3) only 
    for row in ws_obj.iter_rows(min_col=3, max_row=20, max_col=3):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == id:  # id is unique, there is only 1 id which matches, but the id is part of some other values in the same row like above
                print(f"benutzerid: {id}")
                print(ws_obj.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column))
                name = ws_obj.cell(cell.row, cell.column - 2).value  # this is the right column and it is also the first column in the row
                print(f"benutzer: {name}")
                return name # return the name because I have found the right value


benutzerid = "3993fj3a"

print(benutzerid)
if not benutzerid.find("/") >= 0:  # if there is a slash something is wrong
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook("list.xlsx", read_only=True, data_only=True)
    ws_obj = wb_obj.active

    benutzer = search(benutzerid)

    try:
        benutzer
    except NameError:
        benutzer = "UNKNOWNUSER"  # use defaultvalue if no ID is found
    print(f"The user with ID {benutzerid} is {benutzer}")
```

Setting the ID to '3993fj3a' results in returned name 'Mary'

Output

```
3993fj3a
benutzerid: 3993fj3a
<ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.C3>
benutzer: Mary     
User with ID 3993fj3a is Mary
```